# Finding all integer points on a hypersurface

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

> Given a function $f$ of $n$ variables, is there a reasonable way to generate all integer points on the hypersurface given by $f(x)=0$?

To be more specific, let us assume that $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)=0\}$ is bounded. If one knows a bound for the elements of $S$, say, if $S\subset [a,b]^n$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, one can simply iterate over all points $x\in [a,b]^n$ and check whether $f(x)=0$. This approach is insanely inefficient.

One way to reduce the number of operations is to iterate over $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\in[a,b]^{n-1}$ and solve for $x_n$ (numerically and then checking for the nearest integers or by means of the rational root theorem).

One could imagine that there is a way to "move along a hypersurface", that is, only look at the points that are close to $S$. If one has a point $x$ which is close to $S$, it is likely that a point $y$ next to $x$ is close to $S$ as well. So one can move to such a point $y$ and repeat. But not if $y$ gets too far from $S$ (this can be judged by the value $f(y)$, and the gradient of $f$ at $y$ must be taken into account). This, however, requires storing all the integer points already visited, so might take quite a lot of memory (which I would like to avoid). I think this is not trivial even for a plane curve. It there a known way to minimize the number of points visited? In a sense, this look quite similar to the problem of enclosing $S$ inside an "integral envelope", a minimal integral polyhedron which contains $S$ (possibly non-convex and not simply-connected).

To narrow this down even further, let us assume that $f$ is qudratic (and positive-definite), so $S$ is an ellipsoid. I would guess that this particular case is much easier and has been studied before. Any references?

More generally, one can consider unbounded hypersurfaces. Then the problem of visiting all integer points should be reformulated as the problem of walking along the hypersurface and *eventually* visiting eash integer point (instead of, say, getting stuck on a subvariety).

Comment: Since the problem of checking whether a polynomial has integer roots is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem), I don't expect any efficient solutions even for a bounded case. "$f$ is qudratic, so $S$ is an ellipsoid" - I guess you also mean that it's quadratic positive-definite (otherwise roots are not bounded for $x^2 - y^2$). I don't know about quadratic case, but I wouldn't expect anything: while you can rotate/shift coordinate system so that the function becomes $\sum_{i} \lambda_i x_i^2$, I think it'll be nontrivial to find integer original roots.

Comment: For the quadratic case you can see [Grunewald and Segal, On the integer solutions of quadratic equations](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.2004.023/html).

Comment: @Dmitry Is it undecidable in case there is an a priori knowledge that the hypersurface is bounded? This splits into two questions: is it decidable whether the set of (real) solutions is bounded and if so, how to find a bound?

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky, I tried to find some cases for the 10th Hilbert problem, but it took too much time. Yet, I strongly suspect that there are hard cases where "yes"-instances have finite number of roots (and therefore they are bounded), and since the roots for "no"-instances are bounded (since there are no roots), I don't think boundness will help you.